# Calculus Proof / Number Theory

Tags: calculus, number-theory

Let $a_j$ represent a real number such that. 
$$ \frac{\sum_{j=-1}^{n} (n-j)!a_{j+1}}{(n+1)!} = 0$$
Prove $$\sum_{j=0}^{n} a_jx^j =0$$ has at least one solution such that $x \in (0,1)$
I tried to set $x = \frac{1}{k}$ and solve, but I'm not sure how to solve this using calculus. 
Any hints or ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Is there any reason why you're dividing out by $(n+1)!$ in the first equation? That seems redundant.

Comment: That's just how the problem was given. You can also write it as $a_0 + \frac{a_1}{2} +\frac{a_2}{3} +\frac{a_3}{4} + \ldots +\frac{a_n}{n+1} =0$

Comment: that looks like the integral of a polynomial from $0$ to $1$, and they are saying it is zero, and asking for a zero of the polynomial. Rolle? Consider the integral of the polynomial from $0$ to $y$. This is zero for $y=0$ and for $y=1$, then. Rolle?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Is is just me, or does your first equation differs from the one in your comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p(x):=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_nx^n$. Define $$F(x):=\int_{0}^{x}p(t)\text{d}t.$$

The given equation is saying that $F(1)=0$. We also have that $F(0)=0$.

What does Rolle's theorem say?

**Moral:** In calculus the general theorems that tell you about existence of a solution for an equation, are Intermediate value theorem, and Lagrange's theorem and its particular cases like Rolle. Pretty much any other result on existence of solutions of an equation is a consequence of these. So, as soon as you are asked to prove existence of solutions think on them.

Comment: Is his equation in the question the same as the equation in his comment?

Comment: Sometimes the answer they are looking for is not that of the question they are telling you.

Comment: I know, I'm wondering if the question should be updated to reflect that? It would be better if you do the edit, since OP accepted your answer pretty quickly.